# Guice: injecting a parameter used in implementation of abstract method

Tags: java, dependency-injection, abstract-class, guice

Here is an example of the issue I've come across:

```
public interface IFoo { ... }

public abstract class Helper implements IFoo {
  public Helper() { ... }

  protected abstract X helperMethod();
}    

public class Foo extends Helper {
  private final String aaa;

  @Inject
  public Foo(String aaa) { this.aaa = aaa; }

  @Override
  X helperMethod() { doSomethingUsingWhatsInjected(aaa); }
}
```

The issue is that when I bind IFoo to Foo like this:

```
bind(IFoo.class).to(Foo.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

it appears like `helperMethod()` is being called before the `aaa` has been Injected since I'm seeing `aaa` as `null`. But if I instead don't use the class `Helper` and in-line all of its code directly in `Foo`, guice doesn't struggle.

What's the difference between these two approaches? Why is `helperMethod()` called before we know from where we're getting the implementation of `IFoo`? Can we use `Helper` along with injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're not calling `helperMethod` from within `Helper`'s constructor? You omitted that part from the code you posted, but it would match the behavior you're seeing.

```
public class Test {
  interface IFoo { }

  static abstract class Helper implements IFoo {
    Helper() { helperMethod(); }
    abstract void helperMethod();
  }

  static class Foo extends Helper {
    private final String aaa;

    Foo(String aaa) { this.aaa = aaa; }

    @Override
    void helperMethod() { System.out.println(String.valueOf(aaa)); }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Call helperMethod twice:
    // once in the Helper.Helper(), once right here.
    new Foo("expected").helperMethod();
    // output:
    //   null
    //   expected
  }
}
```

The first thing Foo does is implicitly call its superclass constructor, as if you typed `super()`; this necessarily happens as the very first statement in the subclass constructor. Consequently, this happens even before final variables like `aaa` are set, so your overridden method in Foo sees `aaa` as null. As in my example, this is not specific to Guice, but Guice injection can trigger the constructor just like anything else can.

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors) offers a more thorough discussion of this problem.

Comment: You are exactly correct. I checked, and I *am* calling `helperMethod()` from within the constructor of `Helper`. I mistakenly omitted that detail when I wrote my example. This answers my question, thank you!